# further question on the existence of decomposable modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is related to another solved question [submodule of indecomposable module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245444/seeking-an-example-in-module-theory-indecomposable-modules)

It has shown some indecomposable modules have decomposable modules. Now my question is,

**Suppose M is an injective and indecomposable module, can it have an decomposable submodule?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For finite length modules over Artinian rings it can not have such a module, since an indecomposable injective module has simple socle.

Comment: @Julian, can you give some reference?

Comment: Auslander, Reiten, Smalo: Representation theory of artin algebras states in Proposition 4.1 (d): Let $\Lambda$ be an artin algebra. Then a module of finite length is injective if and only if its socle is simple.

Comment: @YACP, sorry for the typoes, I have fixed it. It should be decomposable submodule.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer I think the correct version is : An injective module I is indecomposable if and only if soc I is simple.

Comment: Does this result also hold for projective indecomposable modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible.  I will prove that if an injective module $M$ contains a decomposable module, then $M$ is decomposable.

By hypothesis, $M$ has a submodule of the form $N_1 \oplus N_2$, where each $N_i$ is nonzero.  Because $M$ is injective, it contains a submodule isomorphic to the injective hull $E(N_1 \oplus N_2) = E(N_1) \oplus E(N_2)$ (for this equality, see Lam's *Lectures on Modules and Rings*, equation (3.39)).  Because this is an injective submodule of $M$, we have $M = E(N_1) \oplus E(N_2) \oplus P$ for some submodule $P$.  Because both of the injective hulls $E(N_i)$ are nonzero, it follows that $M$ is decomposable.

The positive way to state this result is that *an injective module is indecomposable if and only if it is uniform.* You can find this statement in the same book by Lam, Theorem 3.52.